# Unity referencing all images in scene instead of just one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the color of an image when I hover over it. It runs `PointerEnter` when I hover over it, and `PointerExit` when my mouse goes away.

Instead of changing the color of just the image I'm hovering over, it changes the color of every image in the scene. Can anybody help?

Here is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class click : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start(){
        
    }

    void Update(){
        
    }
    
    public void PointerEnter(){
        gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().material.color=new Color(1,1,0);
    }
    
    public void PointerExit(){
        gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().material.color=new Color(1,1,1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material is shared for optimisation, it's the same one used for all the images using it.

You need to change the color of the image, simply remove material on your lines.

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color=new Color(1,1,0);
```

The Button component has transition settings where you can set colors for state, maybe you dont need the extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has 2 pre-programmed functions called [`OnMouseOver()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html) and [`OnMouseExit()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseExit.html). Which you can use to see if the mouse entered your `Image`.

You would need to add this Code Snippet to each `Image` you want the `Color` to be changed on Hover and make sure that you get the `.Color` Component instead of the `.material.color` Component.

**Example:**

```cs
public class OnMouseOverExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnMouseOver() {
        // Executes when you Hover over this GameObject with the Mouse
        gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(1f, 1f, 0f);
    }

    void OnMouseExit() {
        // Executes when you no longer Hover over this GameObject with the Mouse
        gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

If you want to change a UI Components `Color`, you could also use the [`Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UIElements.Button.html) Component. Which already has functionality built in, you can use to tint the `Color` of your Image.